# Ad mob prevents app from starting on nougat emulator

Tags: android, admob

After adding admob to my app it works well on kitkat emulator and real mobile, but when tested on nougat emulator it fails .Thanks in advance

[app screenshot jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygXs6.png)

[Adding ad mob code and steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byutw.jpg)

Here is the logcat that appears upon starting the app

```
02-12 23:15:46.608 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-12 23:15:46.608 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
02-12 23:15:46.638 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.wEgyptianpost-2/lib/x86

                                                         [ 02-12 23:15:46.648  1489: 1510 D/         ]
                                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9cc92200, tid 1510
02-12 23:15:46.774 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86
02-12 23:15:46.775 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.webview version 51.0.2704.91 (code 275509110)
02-12 23:15:47.177 2259-2266/com.wEgyptianpost W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.525ms
02-12 23:15:47.227 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 182 ms (timestamps 5375-5557)
02-12 23:15:47.227 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "51.0.2704.91", actual native library version number "51.0.2704.91"
02-12 23:15:47.377 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {f0ca1f0}
02-12 23:15:47.377 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "51.0.2704.91", actual native library version number "51.0.2704.91"
02-12 23:15:47.813 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(143)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
02-12 23:15:48.214 2259-2266/com.wEgyptianpost W/art: Suspending all threads took: 41.274ms
02-12 23:15:48.311 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
02-12 23:15:49.240 2259-2266/com.wEgyptianpost W/art: Suspending all threads took: 65.312ms
02-12 23:15:49.614 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost E/ApkAssets: Error while loading asset assets/natives_blob_64.bin: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/natives_blob_64.bin
02-12 23:15:49.614 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost E/ApkAssets: Error while loading asset assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin

                                                            [ 02-12 23:15:50.790  2259: 2259 D/         ]
                                                            HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9bc92400, tid 2259
02-12 23:15:51.243 2259-2378/com.wEgyptianpost W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
02-12 23:15:51.774 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost I/cr_DRP: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
02-12 23:15:52.121 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:30] Constructor
02-12 23:15:52.141 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
02-12 23:15:52.142 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
02-12 23:15:52.145 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                 --------- beginning of crash
02-12 23:15:52.145 2259-2259/com.wEgyptianpost E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.wEgyptianpost, PID: 2259
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wEgyptianpost/com.wEgyptianpost.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at com.wEgyptianpost.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
02-12 23:16:15.750 2259-2266/com.wEgyptianpost W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.671ms
02-12 23:17:19.554 2259-2266/com.wEgyptianpost W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.155ms
02-12 23:17:29.780 2259-2266/com.wEgyptianpost W/art: Suspending all threads took: 18.873ms
02-12 23:17:29.790 2259-2266/com.wEgyptianpost W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.352ms
```

Here is the main activity code,what is the problem with line 37? (it is the ad request line)

```
package com.wEgyptianpost;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import com.wEgyptianpost.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView view;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.admob_id);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);



        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);
        final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh,R.color.refresh1,R.color.refresh2);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mWebView.reload();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mWebView.stopLoading();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);





                    }
                },10000);
            }
        });
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        //mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        // Use remote resource
         mWebView.loadUrl("http:google.com");

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        // Use local resource
        //mWebView.loadUrl("file:android_asset/web/google.html");


    }



    // Prevent the back-button from closing the app
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

Here is my activity xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


        <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   </ScrollView>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/admob_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1851250777225639/8300259410"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />




</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: need crash log from logcat

Comment: @SteelBytes Hi, I just added it.thanks in advance

Comment: Post your XML file

Comment: @Pztar Hi,I just added the activity xml ,thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Are you sure that your xml is the `activity_main`? Do you have multiple xml layout files?

Comment: @Pztar thank you soooo much I founded another activity xml file named "v23/activity xml"..I went to the file path and kicked it off to the recycle bin, finally it worked on nougat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been two activity xml files, the one i wrote here it is called activity.xml and another one under it in the app called "v23/activity.xml"..I right clicked this v23/activity.xml file and from the list that appeared I choosed file path and I deleted its file.I tried the app on Nougat after that and finally it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fault in line 37 of your MainActivity.
It is invoking `loadAd()` on a reference that is null.

This means that there is no element called `admob_id` in your `activity_main` layout. But we can't confirm that because you haven't pasted your layout xml.